# Updating parse object for current user instead of creating duplicate entry

Tags: ios, swift, parsing

I am trying to let the user update their location. When I try to save the data it creates a duplicate entry instead of updating the old information. I have a heroku parse server deployed to a mongolabs db.

```
class DropLoc: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate { 

var user = PFUser.currentUser()
var post = PFObject(className:"Post")
var query = PFQuery(className:"Post")
var point:  PFGeoPoint!
let porta = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var curGate = porta.location

    self.porta.delegate = self
    self.porta.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.porta.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.porta.startUpdatingLocation()
    point = PFGeoPoint(location: curGate)


    query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user!)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {(objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }else{
            self.post["user"] = self.user ?? NSNull()
            self.post["location"] = self.point ?? NSNull()
            self.post.saveInBackground()

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what my issue was. My problem was that I was querying user and not .username.

```
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
```

Also I needed to set the force the elements to update and if the query fails create a new instance.

```
            query.whereKey("user", equalTo: user!)
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock() {(uobject: PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            self.post["user"] = self.user ?? NSNull()
            self.post["location"] = self.point ?? NSNull()
            self.post.saveInBackground()
        }else if let uobject = uobject{
            uobject["user"] = self.user ?? NSNull()
            uobject["location"] = self.point ?? NSNull()
            uobject.saveInBackground()
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears `point` is only set once. Try adding the following method from the [CLLocationManagerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/) protocol.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {
        // updated coordinate
        point = PFGeoPoint(location: manager.location!)        
}
```

Comment: This didn't change it. It's actually an issue with the query which I still can't figure out